# Переборщик паролей, зависает программа

Tags: c++-cli

Было задание написать программу, которая считывает пароль, введенный пользователем, запоминает его, а потом подбирает его, используя все коды символов ASCII. В общем-то оно всё есть, но есть проблема - работает только при длине пароля 3 символа или меньше. Если больше, то просто зависает, ничего не происходит, никаких ошибок и исключений не выдает, в диспетчере статус "не отвечает". И вторая проблема - не срабатывает первый return из variadic_loop. То есть в if (pass==givenPass) заходит, cout срабатывает, а return - нет, то есть при найденном верном пароле продолжает крутиться до упора, поэтому, например, время работы приходится считать внутри функции.

Windows 8, MS Visual Studio 2013

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    string dispPass;
    if (textBox1->Text != "")
    {
        textBox1->BackColor = SystemColors::Window;

        start_time = clock(); // начальное время

        int asciitotal = 256;
        char ascii[256];
        for (int i = 0; i < asciitotal; i++)
        {
            ascii[i] = i;
        }

        string givenPass;
        givenPass = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(textBox1->Text);

        int len = textBox1->Text->Length;
        cout << givenPass<<endl;

        int *t = new int[len];
        t[len] = { 0 };

        dispPass=variadic_loop(0, len, t, asciitotal, ascii, givenPass);
        label2->Text = gcnew String(dispPass.c_str());

        unsigned int search_time = end_time - start_time; // искомое время
        this->label3->Text = "Время: " + search_time / 1000 + " с";
    }
    else
    {
        textBox1->BackColor = Color::Salmon;
    }
}

string foundPass="";

string variadic_loop(size_t i, size_t n, int *t, int v, char ascii[], string givenPass)
{
    string pass="";
    for (int x = 0; x < n;x++)
        pass.append("x");

    for (t[i] = 32; t[i] < v; t[i]++)
    {
        if (n == i + 1)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < n; x++)
                pass[x] = ascii[t[x]];

            if (pass==givenPass)
            {
                end_time = clock(); // конечное время
                foundPass = "";
                foundPass = foundPass.append(pass);
                cout << "yes"<<endl;
                cout << foundPass << endl;
                return foundPass;
            }
            continue;
        }
        variadic_loop(i + 1, n, t, v, ascii, givenPass);
    }

    return foundPass;
}
```

Comment: Это не C++, это C++/CLI. Исправил метки.